# SAS - Create a dataset with a month column in yymmn6. format

Tags: sas, dataset

I want to create a SAS dataset with just one column having value month in yymmn6. format. The data range should be from

```
 call symput('enddt',trim(left(intnx('month',today(),-2),yymmn6.)));
 call symput('startdt',trim(left(intnx('month',today(),-14),yymmn6.)));
```

Now with this if I do

```
 data months;
    do date = &startdt to &enddt;
      output;
    end;
 run;
```

I am getting output

```
     201511
     201512
     201513
     201514
     201515
     201516
     .
     .
     201610
```

But the result I am looking for is

```
     201511
     201512
     201601
     201602
     201603
     201604
     .
     .
     201610
```

Can someone please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do this slightly differently.  I would do the two bits in one step.

```
data months;
  do mon_incr = -14 to -2;
    date = intnx('month',today(),mon_incr);
    output;
  end;
  format date YYMMN6.;
run;
```

You can PUT the value to a character string if you want in the date= assignment, or leave it a formatted date as I do here.

The problem with what you're doing there is you're converting it to a regular number that has no memory of being a date in the call symput step; so it's seeing

```
do month = 201511 to 201610;
  ...
end;
```

and thinking you mean "do two hundred one thousand five hundred eleven to two hundred one thousand six hundred ten", not "do twenty fifteen november to twenty sixteen october".